# DynamoDB ProjectionExpression to retrieve certain attributes of ALL items in list

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In DynamoDB I have `Player` table, which contains `list` of characters.
Each character is in turn a `map` in DynamoDB terms.
Characters have some attributes like `level`, `exp` and lot of others.
And specific task for me now is to select only certain attributes, not all of them, but for ALL characters, not just for one.
I already understood how to fetch these attributes from single character.
I'm using node.js, so the parameters for me are the following:

```
const params = {
    'TableName': 'Player',
    'Key': { 'APIKey': 'pd-iac3G' },
    'ProjectionExpression': 'characters[0].#level, characters[0].exp',
    'ExpressionAttributeNames': { '#level': 'level' }
};
```

(`level` is reserved keyword, that's why it's extracted into `ExpressionAttributeNames`).

But for fetching these attributes for all characters I'd like to write something like:

```
'ProjectionExpression': 'characters.#level, characters.exp',
```

Or maybe

```
'ProjectionExpression': 'characters[*].#level, characters[*].exp',
```

But I can't find any syntax for that, googling also didn't help, and I started to doubt it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an interesting question, I never had the need to do something like this. Would even argue that this could be viewed as a red flag that it's not the best data model for dynamo.

I would consider either extract the objects of the array to another table or even have the objects in the same table, like they recommend on having the single table design https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-single-table/

If this is something that you can do from what i know only filtering the array and filtering the properties after in the code, without relying on dynamo.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yeah, I was also thinking about extracting list into separate table, that's what I actually planned in the beginning, but then I thought "hmm, that's mostly relational approach, and DynamoDB allows to store nested data, and player can have only 3 characters for now, so why not store them as a nested list". But now I see that if you have problem of selecting subset of data in records, then it's better to use separate table. I was just a bit surprised that DynamoDB has quite flexible expressions, but probably they didn't take this case into account.

Comment: Since they even recommend a single table approach would say that they don't want to support an object with a big array of options. But you will get blocked right on your use case because of this :/
I know that you can do this on other nosql for example MongoDb